# PHP .ZIP object - str_replace folder path?

Tags: php, zip, str-replace

I'm running a script that ZIP's a users personal directory when requested.

The path to that directory is:

**../temp/useremail/**

When the ZIP is actually downloaded, this is also how the folder path appears within it (which obviously looks awful). I want it to appear simply as:

**useremail/**

I tried using a str_replace but it was ineffective. Here's my code:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();


$exists = file_exists('../temp/' . $email . '/theme-' . $email . '.zip');
$delete = '../temp/' . $email . '/theme-' . $email . '.zip';

if($exists) {
    unlink($delete);
}

if ($zip->open('../temp/' . $email . '/theme-' . $email . '.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    die("Could not open archive");
}   

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("../temp/$email/"));

foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    $_key = str_replace("../temp/'.$email.'/", "", $key);
    $zip->addFile(realpath($_key), $_key) or die("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
}

$zip->close();
```

Comment: try `ZipArchive::renameName` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.renamename.php

Comment: Had a quick look but it doesn't seem to help, unless I'm using it wrong that is. How would you integrate that into my current script?

Answer (score 1):

Your way of using str_replace to do it actually works, but you've done a simple mistake.
In this line:

$zip->addFile(realpath($_key), $_key) or die("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");

To fix it, just keep the first parameter of addFile one as $key (which is the longer path / real location of file in the system) and second parameter (the new path in the zip archive) as the edited!

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();


$exists = file_exists('../temp/' . $email . '/theme-' . $email . '.zip');
$delete = '../temp/' . $email . '/theme-' . $email . '.zip';

if($exists) {
    unlink($delete);
}

if ($zip->open('../temp/' . $email . '/theme-' . $email . '.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    die("Could not open archive");
}   

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("../temp/$email/"));

foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    $_key = str_replace("../temp/'.$email.'/", "", $key);
    $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $_key) or die("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
}

$zip->close();
```

That's it!

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference I'm afraid. The zip structure isn't changing at all.